# What is the development flow with a Debian package?

Tags: debian

In the past I used `apt-get source <pkg>`, `apt-get build-dep <pkg>` and `fakeroot debian/rules build`, but I see that not all packages support it and `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc` is recommended, however, I am not interested in generating the packages but only doing the build (compile and link) without installing, after making some changes to the sources (fix or feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
debian/rules build
```

is still *supposed* to work, but many packages rely on `dpkg-buildpackage`’s environment and don’t build correctly, as you’ve noticed.

To work around this, you can run

```
dpkg-buildpackage -T build
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried both with `gimp-2.10.22` (on sid) and they act like the build has been already done (I just downloaded the directory)

Comment: `build-arch` seems to work, thanks, I didn't know about `-T`